# How to dynamically calculate the Partial Derivative of any vector?

Tags: rendering, blender

I have a problem that requires Partial Derivative of X and Partial Derivative of Y

**(Like OpenGL's dFdx() and dFdy() functions.. [OpenGL Registry dFdx](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/dFdx.xhtml))**

However, the issue is, I dont have access to these functions, and I'm basically writing formulas using Math nodes in blender.

**What I want to know is, how can I get the Partial Derivative of any point?**

These are all the pre-existing functions I *can* use:
[image]

Comment: Since this is a question about Blender3D, you may want to ask on [their SE site](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) (and also search before you ask).

Comment: You can try numerical differentiation (e.g. finite differences approximation): https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation